# Perl dereferencing a subroutine

Tags: perl, reference, subroutine

I have come across code with the following syntax:

```
$a -> mysub($b);
```

And after looking into it I am still struggling to figure out what it means. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: [`perldoc perlobj`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlobj)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a [method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)) call. `$a` is the invocant (a class name or an object), `mysub` is the method name, and `$b` is an argument. You should proceed to read [perlootut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html) which explains all of this.

Answer (score 4):

What you have encountered is object oriented perl.

it's documented in [`perlobj`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html). The principle is fairly simple though - an object is a sort of super-hash, which *as well* as data, also includes built in code.

The advantage of this, is that your data structure 'knows what to do' with it's contents. At a basic level, that's just validate data - so you can make a hash that rejects "incorrect" input.

But it allows you to do considerably more complicated things. The real point of it is encapsulation, such that I can write a module, and you can make use of it without really having to care what's going on inside it - only the mechanisms for driving it.

So a really basic example might look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

package MyObject;

#define new object
sub new {
   my ($class) = @_;
   my $self = {};
   $self->{count} = 0;
   bless( $self, $class );
   return $self;
}
#method within the object
sub mysub {
   my ( $self, $new_count ) = @_;
   $self->{count} += $new_count;
   print "Internal counter: ", $self->{count}, "\n";
}

package main;
#create a new instance of `MyObject`. 
my $obj = MyObject->new();
#call the method, 
$obj->mysub(10);
$obj->mysub(10);
```

We define "class" which is a description of how the object 'works'. In this, class, we set up a subroutine called `mysub` - but because it's a class, we refer to it as a "method" - that is, a subroutine that is *specifically* tied to an object.

We create a new instance of the object (basically the same as `my %newhash`) and then call the methods within it. If you create multiple objects, they each hold their own internal state, just the same as it would if you created separate hashes.

Also:  Don't use `$a` and `$b` as variable names. It's dirty. Both because single var names are wrong, but also because these two *in particular* are used for `sort`.

Comment: The second and third paragraph are completely wrong (and the rest just duplicates perlootut). Objects don't have to be hashes. The methods are not in the hash; they're not even associated with the object (like in JS) but with the class. Validation can be done just as easily without OOP. perlootut is a much better reference than perlobj.